# Does toCharArray resize the char array?

Tags: java, arrays

There is a confusion with `toCharArray` in java. While I am writing this code i have noticed that after this line `ch = str.toCharArray();` char array have been resized.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = "helo java";
    char[] ch = new char[str.length() + 1];
    ch = str.toCharArray();
    ch[str.length()] = '\uFDD0';
    for(int i = 0; ch[i] != '\uFFD0'; i++){
        System.out.print(ch[i]);
    }         
}
```

so my question does this function re-size the array ?
sorry for my bad English. Thank you

Comment: This will throw exception `ch[str.length()] = '\uFDD0';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toCharArray()` allocates a *new* character array which means you lose your original array here.

Do like this instead:

```
final CharBuffer charbuf = CharBuffer.allocate(str.length() + 1);
// String implements CharSequence, so this works
charbuf.append(str).append('\uffd0');
// charbuf.array() contains the underlying char array
```

Answer (score 2):

`toCharArray()` method returns new char array, so your previous orginal char array lost
Accroding to [String#toCharArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--)

> Returns a newly allocated character array whose length is the length of this string and whose contents are initialized to contain the character sequence represented by this string.

Comment: Just so you know, the documentation you linked to is two major versions and over 2.5 years out of date. I updated the link to Java 8. If you don't want the change, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I don't want to change it :).Thank you for reminding me about it.

Answer (score 0):

`toCharArray` does not resize the char array.

`char[] ch = new char[str.length() + 1];` creates a new array of length 10. str.length() is 9.

The line `ch = str.toCharArray();` assigns ch to reference a new array that is returned by str.toCharArray(); So now `ch` references an array of size 9.

Now `ch[str.length()]` will result in Exception.

Answer (score 0):

What `char[] ch` is is a reference to an array of chars, you can assign ch to different arrays, for example:

```
char[] a = new char[1];
char[] b = new char[2];

char[] ch;
ch = a; // here ch is pointing to the same array as a, so it's length is 1.
ch = a; // here ch is pointing to the same array as b, so it's length is 2.
```

So you can code what you want like this (Of course there are a lot of possible implementations):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "hello java";
    char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
    ch = Arrays.copyOf(ch, ch.length+1);
    ch[ch.length-1] = '\uFDD0';
    for (int i = 0; i< ch.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(ch[i]);
    }
}
```

As you can see you can use `Arrays.copyOf()` to get a copy of your array resized to a new length, and then introduce your new character there.

Please note that you were iterating using `ch[i] != '\uFFD0'` in your stopping condition, this is not correct in Java since you're comparing the pointers, instead use `!(ch[i].equals('\uFDD0')`